# rails 3: jquery ajax form calling twice?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am seeing quite a weird behavior on a simple form:

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_for @product_list, :url => add_product_admin_product_list_path(@product_list, :product_id => @product), :html => {'data-remote' => true} do |f| %>
  <p class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>"><%= @product.short_description %></p>
  <%= f.submit "Add Item!" unless @product_list.products.include?(@product) %>
<% end %>
```

On the server I am seeing:

```
Started POST "/admin/product_lists/featured-product-list-for-guests/add_product?product_id=fisher-price-rock-a-stack" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Nov 12 15:50:59 +0100 2010
  Processing by Admin::ProductListsController#add_product as JS
  Parameters: {"product_id"=>"fisher-price-rock-a-stack", "authenticity_token"=>"/p5O3g0eY/zgCTq0yL9wG5XZicHrGo/FAXvlNzfoa+s=", "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"featured-product-list-for-guests"}
Completed 200 OK in 154ms (Views: 25.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)


Started POST "/admin/product_lists/featured-product-list-for-guests/add_product?product_id=fisher-price-rock-a-stack" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Nov 12 15:50:59 +0100 2010
  Processing by Admin::ProductListsController#add_product as JS
  Parameters: {"product_id"=>"fisher-price-rock-a-stack", "authenticity_token"=>"/p5O3g0eY/zgCTq0yL9wG5XZicHrGo/FAXvlNzfoa+s=", "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"featured-product-list-for-guests"}
    Completed 200 OK in 125ms (Views: 24.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Basically it is calling this twice!

Also, in my routes I have this:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :product_lists do
      member do
        put :add_product
        put :remove_product
      end
    end
  end
```

I am a bit surprised it has to be a put (a post doesn't work) but maybe that is another question!

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind! It turns out that I was including jquery twice...

FYI if you change this line in application.rb:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails application)
```

You don't need to also include anything new for jquery with a javascript_include_tag